# What are the different kinds of mesh smoothing in Blender?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

So far I only know of Subdivision Surface and its effects. Are there any other types of mesh smoothing available? And what are the differences between each of them?

Comment: Have you seen [blender.org/manual](https://blender.org/manual)?

Comment: @Tejas in particular see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/ "deform" section. But you can also smooth normals, curves, f-curves...